# What does the idiom "to sound a little off" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, american-english

What does the idiom "to sound a little off" mean in American English?

Comment: Are you asking about idioms which don't sound quite right, or are you asking specifically about the idiom "to sound a little off"?

Comment: yes "to sound a little off", please edit my question if you think is not written properly ;-)

Comment: To me this idiom can refer to different things or at least a range of related things, I think we need some context. How did you hear or see this used?

Comment: I heard his idiom during a text revision, they mention some phrase as "to sound a little off". let me know thanks

Comment: We need more context. Was it that an English learner tried to say something in imperfect English, then a native speaker informed them that their attempt didn't sound quite right to them?

Comment: "Sound a little off pitch/off key" (in a figurative sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means “to sound not quite right”.  Three rather literal examples plucked from the web:

> “Sometimes the bass on music will sound a little off, almost distorted.” 
>   “it sounds a little off ’cause i still haven’t tuned it” 
>  “Starting this morning when i turned the truck on i noticed the engine sounds a little off. Kinda like one cylinder isn’t firing. ”

It can also have a slightly metaphorical use, to describe a situation that is not right: e.g., “the price they quoted sounds a little off”.

In a related vein you have “to feel a little off” meaning to feel not quite right, applying both to people and things: “I feel a little off after eating the whole tub of icecream”, “the atmosphere of the meeting felt a little off to me”.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, it could mean "out of context" or "not completely pertaining to the matter being talked about".

Answer (score 1):

It's from [off-key](http://www.wordnik.com/words/off-key) *[music] pitched higher or lower than the correct notes of a melody.*

The word *little* is arbitrary - in other contexts you might say *"That sounds **really** off to me"*.

From which it can be seen that the original/literal sense implies *a bad fit with the surrounding context* (i.e. - the meaning or style of preceding utterances). But in practice today people usually use it to mean *a bad fit with **my** ideas on what you should be saying, or how you should say it*.

Answer (score 0):

If a coffee cup was not placed directly in the center of its saucer, someone might also say it was "a little off".

Also, if someone didn't want a completely dark room and dimmed a nightstand lamp, they might say "I turned it a **little** off." (As opposed to ***completely*** off.)

Comment: "I turned it a little off" actually sounds more than *a little off* to this native British person.  I might say "I turned the light **down a little**".  But a light is either one or off - it can't be *"a little off"*!

Comment: My comment above should (of course)  have read "a light is either *on* or off" - not "*one* or off"!